# How to expand a div to its parent's max-height

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working with an angular dialog layout in which the API to open and manage the dialog comes from a different library. When rendering, the dialog's parent container has a max-height attribute so the dialog's height is determined by the content's height (The dialog's parent container is managed by the library. I just have to supply the child component). So if I put an empty div, the dialog's height is 0 because there's nothing inside the div. How can I make the empty div expand to the max-height of the parent container?

To make this a bit more clear, I've isolated the scenario with an example-

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  background-color: purple;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here I want the child to expand to its parent's max-height (i.e. `100px`). I've tried using `display: flex` on parent and `flex: 1` on the child but it didn't work. Note that I cannot just directly set the child's height to `100px` because this `100px` in my specific example is coming from a different library and I cannot assume it to remain constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the child max height to inherit (so you don't nee to know the value that was set in the parent).

And then you can set the height to something enormous. In your example 100% would do, but that relies on knowing the various positioning of ancestor elements so this snippet puts in something that is likely to be larger than the inherited max-height just as a demo.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .parent {
      background-color: purple;
      max-height: 100px;
    }
    
    .child {
      background-color: red;
      max-height: inherit;
      height: 10000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you inspect computed styles in your browser dev tools you can see the computed value of the child height is 100px which is what you want.

Comment: Perfect! This works as expected. Although I realized my situation is a little different than I modeled previously. In my case, the max-height is set on a grandparent div. We can model it by wrapping the child class div inside another div. In that case, `max-height: inherit` on child will inherit `none` from its parent and not the max-height of its grandparent. How do we solve this?